# Remove parent array including the children if the children value found empty

Tags: php, laravel

I have this array structure.

I'm trying to remove those whole array if I found the `[empevalpptwo]` empty or null, so if the `[empevalpptwo]` is empty the whole `[4] => Array` should be remove.

Right now i'm just trying to get the parent index so I can just remove it by index

Is there any good solution like filtering recursively?

```
$kra = array_column($ppform_plan->toArray(), 'kra');
$emp_eval_pptwo = array_search('', array_column($kra, 'empevalpptwo'));
//should return 4


Array
(
    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 50
            [user_id] => 6282
            [specific_user_id] => 6281
            [eval_cat_id] => 2
            [format_cat] => 1
            [title] => This istesting
            [desc] => 
            [weight] => 50
            [bsc_weight_group] => 
            [bsc_rating] => 
            [sequence] => 
            [created_at] => 2019-05-22 10:55:23
            [updated_at] => 2019-05-22 10:55:23
            [kra] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 77
                            [user_id] => 6282
                            [bsc_id] => 50
                            [index] => 0
                            [kra_title] => ttes lang muna
                            [kra_desc] => 
                            [kra_weight] => 25
                            [sat] => 521
                            [at] => 4
                            [ot] => 535
                            [rating_per_kra] => 
                            [rating_per_kra_cat] => 
                            [net_weighting] => 5
                            [rank] => 1
                            [remarks] => 
                            [indicator_text] => 
                            [created_at] => 
                            [updated_at] => 
                            [empevalpptwo] => 
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 78
                            [user_id] => 6282
                            [bsc_id] => 50
                            [index] => 1
                            [kra_title] => talga e2 pa o
                            [kra_desc] => 
                            [kra_weight] => 25
                            [sat] => 5
                            [at] => 2
                            [ot] => 4
                            [rating_per_kra] => 
                            [rating_per_kra_cat] => 
                            [net_weighting] => 4
                            [rank] => 2
                            [remarks] => 
                            [indicator_text] => 
                            [created_at] => 

                        [updated_at] => 
                        [empevalpptwo] => 
                    )
            )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something akin to:

```
<?php

$items =
[
    1 =>
    [
        'foo'=>
        [
            [
                'bar' => '',
            ],
            [
                'bar' => '',
            ]
        ]
    ],
    2 =>
    [
        'foo'=>
        [
            [
                'bar' => 'baz'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

foreach ($items as $k => $item)
    if(empty(array_filter(array_column($item['foo'], 'bar'))))
        unset($items[$k]);

var_export($items);
```

Output:

```
array (
  2 => 
  array (
    'foo' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'bar' => 'baz',
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this :

```
$data = array_map('array_filter', $data);
$data = array_filter($data);
```

**UPDATED**

and for checking inner values you can use this :

```
$array = array_filter($array, function($v) { return !empty($v['empevalpptwo']); });
```

Orginal

```
Array
(
    [con] => Array
        (
            [address] => Array
                (
                    [city] => ahmedabad
                )

            [personalinfo] => 
        )

)
```

Result :

```
Array
(
    [con] => Array
        (
            [address] => Array
                (
                    [city] => ahmedabad
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: I read the OP's problem as if a particular leaf is empty, remove the array all the way to the root.